# How to create reusable Durandal widgets

Tags: javascript, css, git, widget, durandal

I'd like to get going on creating my own little library of reusable Durandal widgets.

Thanks to the docs, creating a widget wasn't difficult, but I couldn't find information about how to package / how to import a widget in a way that would naturally integrate with a Durandal project.

More specifically:

1. The "How to create a widget" page tells me to put the code for each
   widget into a  subdirectory of `assets/javascripts/app/widgets`. I
   suppose I could do that, but wouldn't  it be more natural to use a
   subdirectory of `assets/javascripts/vendor/` so that widgets  could
   be installed by the package manager?
2. How should I provide/package the CSS for my widgets? The mimosa build system which I use automatically includes all the style files under `assets/stylesheets`, but not those in `assets/javascripts/app/widget/<my-widget>`, meaning that I would have to split up the files of each of my widgets into two folders.

Of course, these questions are not show-stoppers, and if I can't get good answers here, I will just fall back to using Durandal the way I know it will work.

Yet it would be really helpful if there was a way to package and install widgets into nicely separated and self-containing directory trees. Even without a package manager, widgets could then be kept as git submodules, which would be great especially during development.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the [mimosa-require-library-package](https://github.com/dbashford/mimosa-require-library-package) a try.  You could toss that in git with a bower.json and use mimosa-bower to pull in the file you are interested in.

Comment: David, thanks for your answer, and sorry for having somehow missed it!  I have (for now?) stopped experimenting with Mimosa and Durandal, and am now working with Knockout and Gulp. But the needs stays similar, so I found myself doing, with Gulp, something very similar to what your library does (though I'm only doing the global export for now, while working with AMD internally). I'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: Sounds good.  Mimosa will be there if you ever want to try it again. =)